# Validate field count in angular form

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-validation, angularjs-forms

I have a form where a model contains an array of sub-models, like this:

```
<form name="form1">
    <div ng-repeat="sub in model.submodels">
        <input ng-model="sub.name" required>
        <button ng-click="delSubmodel($index)">x</button>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addSubmodel()">+</button>
    <button ng-disabled="form1.$invalid" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

How can I make form invalid when there are no input fields (or, in general, when the count of input fields is less than/greater than some value)

**Update**: Thanks for responses, I hope this can be done outside of controller.

Comment: What do you mean with "when there are no input fields"?

Comment: You kind of answered your own question. Just check the value of model.subModels.length, and then invalidate if .length <= 0.

Comment: @aganglada In the example provided, if `model.submodels` is an empty array, there will be no input fields generated, which is invalid in my case.

Comment: @Vinny Where should I insert this check so it was used "angular way"? I definitely should not modify `form1.$invalid` directly. I want it to be set by angular validation mechanics.

Comment: @checat in your controller. When you initialize your controller you should probably invalidate the form (I am assuming you will have no submodels). Then as you click delSubmodel and addSubmodel you should check the amount of submodels, and if necessary, invalidate/validate the form.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I just got what you want to achieve, you will had to add a constraint to the form, which is the size of the subModel, so in your submit method:

Before doing anything

```
$scope.form1.$setValidity('size', model.subModels.length <= 0);
```

This will set the validity of the form to false in case your condition is false, or viceversa, you can also show a message to notify it to the user, adding this:

```
<form name="form1">
<div ng-repeat="sub in model.submodels">
    <input ng-model="sub.name" required>
    <button ng-click="delSubmodel($index)">x</button>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="size" ng-model="model.subModels.length" />
<button ng-click="addSubmodel()">+</button>
<button ng-disabled="form1.$invalid" type="submit">Save</button>
```

You can check this [example](http://goo.gl/tYzNBX) if you don't feel you didn't understood well my point, which is doing the same, just changing the validity for a single input.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! Unfortunately, I believe that simple validation should be done outside of controller. I thought about adding "max" validation on the hidden input, but that's kind of workaround too.